# Realm Object Server on Alibaba Cloud ECS

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

I'm just teaching myself developing iOS App using swift. I use Realm instead of Core Data for local data storage and I find it very intuitive. For remote storage and database, because I have zero backend experience, I've been using firebase for all the works behind the scene and I think it's perfect for my needs as well.

However, I want to test out my app in China and clearly Firebase is not an option (everything google related is blocked). It seems to me AWS is also quite handicapped in China as well (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've done a little research and found that Alibaba cloud ECS seems to be a good choice, also it seems Realm Object Server is becoming more and more exciting with many new features. But before I invest in subscribing to Alibaba cloud ECS I would like to know:

1. If anyone has tried to deploy the Realm Object Server on Alibaba cloud ECS? Can I just follow the [Realm Object Server tutorial](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/deployment/) and set up everything without too much trouble?
2. With Realm Object Server and a cloud ECS do I still need other DB like Postgres/MongoDB/MySQL/Ejabberd? My app would involve some chat functionalities, you can treat it just like whatsapp. Once again I know nothing about backend development so it would be great if someone can shine some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Alibaba Cloud ECS is nothing but a simple virtualisation, If you can set this up in a local virtual/normal linux machine then you can also do it in ECS.

My best suggestion is to checkout the "Message and Notification Services" of Alibaba Cloud. which greatly removes the effort of doing all this. I have created a sample messaging app using the same. Please feel free to checkout the code and reuse it

https://github.com/saichandu415/MNS-Android-Sample

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the great possible alternatives to the above solutions could be use of NoSQL databases like Table Store.

You could use this [guide](http://docs-aliyun.cn-hangzhou.oss.aliyun-inc.com/pdf/ots-Getting-Started-intl-en-2018-07-24.pdf?spm=a2c63.p38356.a3.5.2bde3befhI5iP9&file=ots-Getting-Started-intl-en-2018-07-24.pdf), which is pretty straightforward. You create a server, configure it (it's really simple) and later could use API or SDK that supports all major languages for making queries to it. One of the advantages of this solution is the simplicity of working with data - you don't need to create complex table schemas but just use highly effective storage.